# Validation in a Datagridview

Tags: validation, datagridview, cell

I have an application with a datagrid view

This datagrid is filled by code, not binded to a datasource.
All cells are editable

when a user edits a value in a cell, then i need to perform an action

```
    Private Sub dgView_CellValidated(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) 
      Handles dgView.CellValidated
    Dim nColumnIndex As Integer
    DIm nRowIndex as Integer
    If sender.iscurrentRowDirty Then
        nRowIndex = e.RowIndex
        nColumnIndex = e.ColumnIndex
        Call UpdateRowData(nRowIndex, nColumnIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

The Function UpdateRowData is called when user edits en then leave the cell, but if he goes to a cell in the same row. Then this routine will be called again when the user again goes to another cell without any editing

I want this function only called once

Comment: I may not be following exactly... when do you want to call the code to “perform an action”? When a user simply “leaves” a cell without necessarily “changing” the data in that cell? This looks like what you are currently doing. You are correct that “some” events may not fire if the user selects another cell in the same row. However, the `CellValidated` event is not one of them… it will fire when the user leaves the cell. You state that … _"I want this function only called once”_ … and when would this be?

Comment: I only want the code to perform the action when the user leaves the cell which he just edited. If he enters the cell again and leaves without editing the code shouldn't be launced.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to know if the cell’s value had “actually” changed from its original value? And what is this “action” that is taken if the cell “was” changed? Is what I am getting at… is that it is unclear “what” this “action” is doing? If it is an extensive process that may take some time and you want to avoid this “action” if the cells value doesn’t “actually” change. Then you will need to know if a cells value actually DID change. And this will require a different event and some additional code implementation on your part.

On the other hand, if the “action” is simply to update something with the new value, then it may take MORE execution steps to actually “check” if the value has changed as opposed to simply overwriting the same values. So, if the “action” is trivial, I wouldn’t bother “checking” if the values have changed.

However, if you DID need to make sure that the user “actually” did change the cells value… Then below is a crude, yet simple, solution for this.

One possible issue is if the user clicked into a cell and edited it by “actually” typing some characters, but, after the user finishes typing characters they had ended up simply re-typing what the original value was… then “technically” from the grids perspective… THAT cells value DID change. In other words, We will need to somehow get the original value of the cell “BEFORE” the user starts to edit the cell. Then we could “compare” the new value with the original value when the user tries to leave the cell.

Fortunately, there is a grid event that should make this fairly trivial to implement. The event I suggest using is the grids `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event. This event will actually fire TWICE. The event will fire once when the cell goes into “edit” mode. And it will fire again when the user ends the same cells edit mode.

Therefore, we can take advantage of this, however, we will need to know that WHEN the event fires… is it fired when the user “enters” the cells edit mode… OR … is the event fired because the user is “ending” the cells edit mode. I do not think the event keeps track of this internally so we need to create our own “mechanism” to be able to distinguish when the event is fired on the “begin” edit and the “end” edit.

One possible solution to make this work is to create two global variables… one a `bool` variable called `FirstIn` and a `string` variable called `OriginalValue`… When the event fires the first time to “begin” the cells edit mode, we can check the `FirstIn` variable. If it is `true` then we know the cell is “beginning” the edit of the cell… this is where we would capture the cells current value and set the `OrignalValue` `string` variable so we can “check” it against the final cells value when the user ends the cells edit mode.

Capturing the current cells value and setting `FirstIn` to `false` is all we need to do. We now wait until the user ends the cells edit mode and the event fires for the second time. When it fires the second time… again we check the `FirstIn` variable and in this case it is `false` which means the cells is ending its edit mode. Here we could check the `OriginalValue` with the cells current value and do your “action” if they are different. And finally setting `FirstIn` to `true` to start the whole process over.

Below is an example of what is described above.

```
bool FirstIn = true;
string OriginalValue;

private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (FirstIn) {
    FirstIn = false;
    OriginalValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
  }
  else {
    string NewValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    FirstIn = true;
    if (OriginalValue.Equals(NewValue)) {
      MessageBox.Show("NO changes were made in the cell edit");
    }
    else {
      MessageBox.Show("YES changes were made in the cell edit");
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry but I wrote this in C#, below is a VB version.

```
Dim FirstIn As Boolean = True
Dim OriginalValue As String

Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
  If (FirstIn) Then
    FirstIn = False
    OriginalValue = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()
  Else
    Dim NewValue As String = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()
    FirstIn = True
    If (OriginalValue.Equals(NewValue)) Then
      MessageBox.Show("NO changes were made in the cell edit")
    Else
      MessageBox.Show("YES changes were made in the cell edit")
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```